# ¿Cómo puedo iniciar una actividad en kotlin cuando mi app está en segundo plano?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-intent

[image: Mis intentos de iniciar MainActivity]
Cómo puedo iniciar una actividad cuando mi app está en segundo plano? Es decir, cuando no ha sido destruida? He probado con un IntentService y nada, solo quiero hacer un StartActivity para lanzar mi MainActivity en segundo plano.

Comment: qué has intentado? sin códio es dificil ayudar

Comment: @L.Ronquillo Creo que no es necesario porque todo lo que he intentado no ha funcionado de nada. Igual editaré mi pregunta para poner código